# Exception in thread "main" javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file

Tags: java, javax.imageio

```
package eclipsePackage;

import java.awt.Graphics2D; 

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage; 

import java.io.File; 

import java.io.IOException; 

import javax.imageio.ImageIO; 

public class ImageProcessing {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


             // Read an image. 

        String img= "C:/eclipse/cat1.jpeg";

             BufferedImage input = ImageIO.read(new File(img)); 

             // Create a black-and-white image of the same size. 

             BufferedImage im = 

               new BufferedImage(input.getWidth(),input.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY); 

             // Get the graphics context for the black-and-white image. 

             Graphics2D g2d = im.createGraphics(); 

             // Render the input image on it. 

             g2d.drawImage(input,0,0,null); 

             // Store the resulting image using the PNG format. 

             ImageIO.write(im,"JPEG",new File("rendered_cat1.jpeg")); 


    }
```

Comment: Either the file doesn't exist, or you don't have the permissions to access it in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `C:\\eclipse\\cat1.jpeg`